# How to write a how to write question?

Tags: discussion

I have several questions regarding the art of writing different types of scenarios, however what is the best practice of constructing such questions so they stay in the realm of being on topic?

Examples of mine :

(1) How to write a detailed instructional scene?

(2) How to write a story telling scene?

(3) How to write scenes that do not fall into a repetitive structure?

Comment: Can you give us a few examples?

Comment: A few examples of mine, or from others?

Comment: I meant yours, but your edit is perfect.